# Junit testcase for amazon Rekognition

Tags: junit, amazon-rds

How can i write a test case in Junit for amazon Rekognition.

```
public class SearchFaceMatchingImageCollection {
    public static final String collectionId = "MyCollection";
    public static final String bucket = "bucket";
    public static final String photo = "input.jpg";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AmazonRekognition rekognitionClient = AmazonRekognitionClientBuilder.defaultClient();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // Get an image object from S3 bucket.
        Image image=new Image()
                      .withS3Object(new S3Object()
                      .withBucket(bucket)
                      .withName(photo));

      // Search collection for faces similar to the largest face in the image.
         SearchFacesByImageRequest searchFacesByImageRequest = new SearchFacesByImageRequest()
                .withCollectionId(collectionId)
                .withImage(image)
                .withFaceMatchThreshold(70F)
                .withMaxFaces(2);
         SearchFacesByImageResult searchFacesByImageResult = 
           rekognitionClient.searchFacesByImage(searchFacesByImageRequest);

         System.out.println("Faces matching largest face in image from" + photo);
         List < FaceMatch > faceImageMatches = searchFacesByImageResult.getFaceMatches();
         for (FaceMatch face: faceImageMatches) {
             System.out.println(objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
              .writeValueAsString(face));
             System.out.println();
  }
}
}
```

For the above program I wanted to write a Junit testcase. Kindly help me with the same

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you also please tell, what level of testing? Unit level or Integration?

Comment: unit testing. I know there is an interface called rekognitioniface which is amazon rekognition testing interface but i don't know how to use it . Kindly help me with the same.